# Open a different website to a new window with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have `<a href="http://google.com" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><i className="fab fa-github-alt" aria-hidden="true" /></a>`

How do I use React Router open a different website from the current website that I am on to a new window with React Router?

Comment: What's wrong with the `<a href="" target="_blank">`? React Router does the routing within your app, can't touch the external website.

Comment: Why would you do that with React Router if you can do it with html? React Router is aimed to navigate through your webapp.

Comment: No, React solution to do this way?

Comment: Use a normal `<a>` element. That's what it's there for...

Comment: I posted my solution below. It might be unnecessary to use React but I was curious about how to use it. `<a>` tag is working too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by set `state`

```
state = {
    redirect: false
  }
  setRedirect = (href) => {
    window.location.href = href;
  }
```

and then call it with `onClick`. This will open the target site in a new window.

```
<a onClick={()=>this.setRedirect('http://google.com')}>Project link</a>
```

Comment: OP wants to mimic `target="_blank"`, i.e. open in a new window, so it should call `window.open` instead.